# Create ssl cert error "Correct value not found for DNS challenge"

Tags: ssl, heroku

Creating a certificate on sslforfree.com for a custom subdomain on a Heroku app, I get this error:

```
Domain "xx.xx.com" challenge3 failed. Response from "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/xxx" was: { "type": "dns-01", "status": "invalid", "error": { "type": "urn:acme:error:unauthorized", "detail": "Correct value not found for DNS challenge", "status": 403 }, "uri": "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/challenge/xxx", "token": "xxx", "keyAuthorization": "xxx" }
```

I created a CSR following the heroku instructions, adding the domain name in the Common Name.

The domain has a CNAME on AWS Route53 to the domain name suffixed by `.herokudns.com`. This worked for me before on a multi subdomain cert from sslforfree.com. I can't remember what I did differently last time. I tried changing the CNAME to the .herokuapp.com url first, but same error.

Comment: Do you have something in your app that handles acme challange?

Comment: Yes I have TXT records that are working successfully

Comment: This week Heroku introduced automatic ssl management so you don't need to do it manually https://blog.heroku.com/announcing-automated-certificate-management